# Asset Versioning Not Working - Users Seeing Old Site - Angularjs, SPA

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, single-page-application, gulp-replace

My current stack is Angularjs, Gulp, NPM, etc. - so it is a single page app.

On build, I'm minifying my JS and styles and putting in a distribution file. Along with this build I am doing a gulp-replace in my index.html file to set a version on the JS/CSS.

Index before building

```
<script src="scripts.min.js?v=[replace]"></script>
```

After build

```
<script src="scripts.min.js?v=abc123"></script>
```

Every build changes the query param value. Note that I DID double check that each production build is changing the query param value - still to no avail!

**Issue:** this asset versioning does not appear to force the clients to refetch assets (they are still seeing old scripts/styles on the site).

**Q** - What the heck is happening here? How can I version my assets properly so that users will always get the new versions?

Comment: You have used the right trick! Now, the only thing that would prevent it to work is if your html page itself isn't correctly fetched. Could you check if it is cached?

Comment: @Salketer I will check this again, but I believe I have. As I mentioned in the post, when looking at the markup using Chrome tools, the version does switch. If the HTML was caching, I would imagine it wouldn't show the new version.

Comment: @Salketer I believe you may be right about the index.html file. I notice on refresh it is returning a 304 not modified on the HTML file and the cache control is set to expire a week out. With this said, how am I supposed to do this? A lot of posts insist on caching, but in this case I feel like I should avoid caching the index.html altogether. Thoughts?

Comment: Look out when using the Chrome Tools, there's a box you can check to disable caching, this would prevent you from assessing the problem effectively. Cache is important but it is less than your user experience...